# Is there such thing as a 28 inch wheel?

Tags: tire, wheels

I'm looking at puncture-resistant tires and I see Schwalbe Marathons* listed for size 28 x 1 1/2.  Are there 28 inch wheels?  If not, what size is that meant to fit?

( * Schwalbe Marathon Plus HS 440 Wire Tire)

Comment: Ask Sheldon  http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html

Comment: I know what I'll be reading this weekend ...

Comment: In short: Always look for the ETRTO sizes (e.g. 37-622).

Answer (score 7):

Schwalbe is one of the few brands that lists tire sizes this way. Their 28's come in two ISO's. Tires listed as a decimal size such as 28x2.0 are a 622mm ISO, while tires with a fractional size such as 28 x 1-1/2 are a 635mm ISO.

635mm are an uncommon size to American markets but can be found on

> "English, Dutch, Chinese, Indian Rod-brake roadsters"

from varying manufacturers and production dates.
From [Sheldon Brown](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html)

622mm are commonly referred to as 29 and 700C sizes, which are commonly found on current production mountain and road bikes. 29 and 700C tires are interchangeable as long as the rim width can support the size of the chosen tire. For example a 700 x 50 tire roughly equates to a 29 x 2.00 , or in Schwalbe terms 28 x 2.00"

*Answer has been edited thanks to people paying more close attention to the question than I did.

Comment: -1 for being wrong. 28 x 1.5 is the 622mm size, 28 x 1 1/2 is 635mm. Yes, there are two different 28" sizes.

Comment: @ojs is correct. I just looked on Schwalbe site and the [Marathon Plus HS 440](https://www.schwalbetires.com/bike_tires/road_tires/Marathon_Plus_HS440) has 28 x 1 1/2  size listed as 40-635 (635 mm ISO).  Apparently, this was used on English, Dutch, Chinese, Indian Rod-brake roadsters ([Sheldon](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html)). Please revise

Comment: It's also still somewhat common in Scandinavia.

Comment: Note that a 27 inch rim is smaller than a 28 inch rim but larger than a 29 inch rim.

Comment: There are two different 28 inch rims, one of which is same as 29 but smaller than 27 and another which is larger than 27, 29 or the other 28.

Comment: @ojs Waaaait. So "1.5" isn't the same thing as "1 1/2" to these people? That's appalling.

Comment: To quote Sheldon Brown, "If two tires are marked with sizes that are mathematically equal, but one is expressed as a decimal and the other as a fraction, these two tires will not be interchangeable." Now that you have seen it, you can't unsee it.

Comment: Totally missed he was asking about a 28 x 1-1/2 not a decimal tire, comments are correct, my mistake. Ill edit the answer to be correct. Thanks folks

Comment: Changed the vote to up.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is.  He is a [picture](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/41105/700c-28er-same-as-29er) of one from another SE post which is directly related to your question and shows the type of wheel.

Comment: 28 x 1 1/2 is 635mm which is the other 28"

Comment: That post doesn't discuss which versions of "28-inch" tires will or won't fit the wheel.

Comment: @DanielRHicks the op asks "are there 28 in wheels". The answer is yes and referenced question shows this.